# I Want to build a private GSM Network using OPENBTS and Gnu Radio and HACKRF?Is it possible to build one?

Tags: gsm, gnuradio, cellular-network, private-network

I would like to know is it possible and if it is then how can it be done .Any materials sources to get started with for help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is the hackrf is only half duplex, GSM requires full duplex operation. So you would need two hackrf's. Easier just to get one USRP.